# Flutter : How to avoid specifying absolute height to Container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am wrapping a Container over GridView with Axis as Horizontal.
I need to specify a absolute height for the same, which I want to avoid, because my child widget of GridView will scale as per device pixels and accordingly  the wrapper Container should expand. Please find below code :

```
Container(
          height: 416,
          child: GridView.count(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(kGroupPadding, spacing,kGroupPadding,spacing),
              mainAxisSpacing: GutterSpacing.spacing10,
              crossAxisSpacing: GutterSpacing.spacing10,
              crossAxisCount: itemsLength > 5 ? 2 : 1,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              childAspectRatio: GutterRatio.ratio1_35,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              primary: false,
              children: [for (var item in model.items) builder(context,item as cm.LockableItem)]),
        ),
```

I tried wrapping GridView with AspectRatio, but the ratio specified works for iphone causes issue for xhdpi ad xxhdpi Android devices.

```
AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 0.92,
          child: GridView.count(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(kGroupPadding, spacing,kGroupPadding,spacing),
              mainAxisSpacing: GutterSpacing.spacing10,
              crossAxisSpacing: GutterSpacing.spacing10,
              crossAxisCount: itemsLength > 5 ? 2 : 1,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              childAspectRatio: GutterRatio.ratio1_35,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              primary: false,
              children: [for (var item in model.items) builder(context,item as cm.LockableItem)]),
        ),
```

Also tried wrapping GridView with IntrinsicHeight, Expanded but there is a runtime exception as it fails to render the widget because size property isn't mentioned.

```
    ======== Exception caught by scheduler library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
Updated layout information required for _RenderScrollSemantics#3b8da NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT to calculate semantics.
'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2741 pos 12: '!_needsLayout'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2741:12)
#3      RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#4      RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#5      RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#6      RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#7      RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#8      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3406:14)
#9      RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#10     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#11     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#12     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#13     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#14     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#15     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#16     ContainerRenderObjectMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3406:14)
#17     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#18     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#19     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#20     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#21     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#22     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#23     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#24     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#25     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#26     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#27     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#28     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#29     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#30     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#31     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#32     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#33     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#34     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#35     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#36     ContainerRenderObjectMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3406:14)
#37     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:398:11)
#38     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#39     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#40     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#41     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#42     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#43     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#44     Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:279:35)
#45     RenderViewportBase.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:222:10)
#46     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#47     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#48     RenderIgnorePointer.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3324:14)
#49     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#50     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#51     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#52     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#53     RenderSemanticsAnnotations.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:4721:11)
#54     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#55     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#56     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#57     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#58     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#59     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#60     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#61     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#62     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#63     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#64     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#65     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#66     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#67     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2753:61)
#68     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3122:14)
#69     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2830:5)
#70     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2751:5)
#71     RenderObject._updateSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2719:41)
#72     PipelineOwner.flushSemantics (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1074:16)
#73     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:502:21)
#74     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#75     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#76     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1145:15)
#77     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#78     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:996:5)
#82     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:150:10)
#83     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:270:5)
#84     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:114:31)
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)
```

Thanks in advance for any solutions / suggestions

Comment: What's the purpose of your `Container`? Looks like you can just remove it.

Comment: GridView fails to render if not wrapped inside a container. Ideally based on childaspectratio GridView height should be set. But for axis horizontal it doesn't work.

Comment: That's probably related to the parent widget, not related to `GridView` itself. Are you using a `Column` or something on the outside?

Comment: Have you found the answer to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `MediaQuery. of(context). size. height` to get the height of the device screen you are using and divide it with integer as per your need.

Comment: But again that would be a specific height. This creates issue if inner child Widget height increases. Is there something like wrap_content where the parent would resize as per child

Comment: Wrapping GridView with `Expanded` and making `shrinkWrap=true` for GridView will solve it .

Comment: Tried the same, but it fails to render.